# Effect of conditioning on quantiles

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Cross posted on Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/565661/effect-of-conditioning-on-quantiles

Suppose that we have three continuous, independent, non-negative random variables $X,Y,Z$. Fix $q\in(0,1)$ and suppose that $$q=\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leqslant \tau)=\mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z\leqslant \pi).$$

For $\mu>0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant \mu)>0$, is it true that $$\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leqslant \tau|X\leqslant \mu) \geqslant \mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z\leqslant \pi|X\leqslant \mu)?$$

In other words, what effect does replacing the unconditional sums $X+Y, X+Y+Z$ with $(X+Y)|(X\leqslant \mu)$, $(X+Y+Z)|(X\leqslant \mu)$ have on the quantiles?

Comment: Simulations was my first step. I tried a few, and they all agreed with this inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a handwaving argument for the inequality, illustrated with an example using identical uniform distributions but I thing it could be extended to the general case:

To have $q=\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leqslant \tau)=\mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z\leqslant \pi)$ you need $\tau$ to be a tighter constraint than $\pi$ as shown in the pink and cyan here: remember that a diagonal line from the vertices across a square cuts off half the area while a similar diagonal plane from the vertices across a cube cuts off a third of the volume.

[image]

So when you condition on $X \leqslant \mu$, the removed part has a lower ratio of original probability corresponding to $X+Y\leqslant\tau$  in the 2D case than corresponding to $X+Y+Z\leqslant \pi$  in 3D when compared to their complements of $X+Y\gt \tau$ of $X+Y+Z\gt \pi$.  This has the direct consequence that in the retained part (illustrated in green) there is a higher ratio in the 2D case than the 3D case; both ratios increase but the in the 2D case it increases more.  This means $\mathbb{P}(X+Y\leqslant \tau|X\leqslant \mu) \geqslant \mathbb{P}(X+Y+Z\leqslant \pi|X\leqslant \mu)$

[image]

Comment: I like the intuition behind this answer, but I don't see how it generalizes from the iid uniform case. In the general case, we're integrating a joint pdf over the indicated regions. There could be some strange goings-on in the region outside the red triangle in the left image but inside the base of the blue simplex in the right picture.

Comment: The answer to the question is no.

Comment: @user469053 You can answer your own question with a counter-example if you wish