# Thresholding a sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have two continuous, non-negative, independent random variables $Y,Z$.  Suppose also that $0<a<b$ are such that $$0<\mathbb{P}(Y\leqslant a)=\mathbb{P}(Y+Z\leqslant b).$$  Is it true that for all $t>0$, $$\mathbb{P}(Y\leqslant t+a)\geqslant \mathbb{P}(Y+Z\leqslant t+b)?$$

I have run simulations and done exact computations for a number of specific distributions, and everything agrees with this inequality so far.

EDIT: I have added the requirement that $0<\mathbb{P}(Y\leqslant a)$, because examples where the threshold $a$ is below the minimum of $Y$ yield counterexamples which do not affect the intended applications.

Comment: Let $Y=1$ almost surely and $Z=1$ almost surely. Then choosing $a=0.5$ and $b=1.75$ satisfies the first condition. But for $t=0.25$, we have $P(Y\leq 0.75)=0 < 1= P(Y+Z\leq 2)$

Comment: Thanks for this example. Of course, this $Y$ and $Z$ are not continuous. I have edited the question, as counterexamples like this (where the thresholds are below the minima of the variables) are outside the scope of my intended applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $Y$ to be an independent mixture of uniform random variables: e.g.
$$
Y \sim \begin{cases} \mathrm{Unif}[0, 1] & \text{with probability } 1/2, \\ \mathrm{Unif}[100, 101] & \text{with probability} 1/2. \end{cases}
$$
Let $Z \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0, 1)$, say. Then $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq 1) = 1/2 = \mathbb{P}(Y + Z \leq 2)$ (so $a = 1$, $b = 2$). But for any $0 < t < 99$, $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq 1 + t) = 1/2 < \mathbb{P}(Y + Z \leq 1 + t)$.

Comment: Since this question has a negative answer, let me draw attention to the question which inspired this one. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4385830/effect-of-conditioning-on-quantiles